# How to set up a dropdown list in the view from a dictionary, which has been set up in Umbraco back office with key value pair

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have installed `Key Value Pair` package in `Umbraco` back office and created a some key value pairs and I am trying to get those within the `View` to populate the `dropdownlist`.

```
@{
     if (CurrentPage.HasValue("superHeros"))
     {
         <ul>
              @foreach (var item in CurrentPage.superHeros.Split(','))
                   {
                        <li>@item</li>
                    }
          </ul>
     }
}
```

Second options

```
@if (Model.Content.HasValue("superHeros"))
{
     var preValue = Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("superHeros"));
     <p>@preValue</p>
 }
```

Non of them working though. How do I need to call it in the `View`?

Comment: What is not working? Have you tried outputing the value? `@(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("superHeros")` Does it output anything? I assume you're getting a list of id's of prevalues as a string? In that case you'll have to read it as a string `GetPropertyValue<string>`, use Split(',') to separate, parse them as an int (int.Parse) and retrieve the PreValue using Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString

Comment: It throws an error. I have only created the key value pairs in the back office and that is it. First of all, in the `View` it throws an error on the `CurrentPage` method and will not even render it. In the second version it throws an error on the `Content` method. Am I missing a using statement or some logic within the `SurfaceController`?

Comment: Is your view inheriting from `UmbracoTemplatePage` ?

Comment: What error does it throw?